# How do I Join the line above after current line?

Tags: vim, join, lines

I know these commands in Vim:

> J  : Join line below after current line
>   -J : Join current line after line above

but how do I join the line above after current line?

Comment: `kddpkJ`.......?

Comment: To save a keystroke, `ddkPJ`. And if you do a lot of line swapping, consider making [mappings like in this tip](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/VimTip646#Mappings_to_move_lines).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do it. One would be… deleting the line above and appending it to the end of the line below:

```
k move up one line
^ move to the first printable character
y$ yank to the end of the line
"_d get rid of the now useless line by deleting it into the black hole register
$ move to the end of the line
p put the deleted text
```

Comment: It would be easier to first swap the lines and then `J`oin them (as [@WilliamPursell suggests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13609736/how-do-i-join-the-line-above-after-current-line#comment18659642_13609736)).

Comment: Yes I know. I went for a "litteral" approach. I'd go with William Pursell's method too, actually.

Comment: Note that `J` does handle spaces differently from a verbatim join. That is, if one wants the results that would be produced by `J`, `k^d$k$p` would do something different!

Comment: In my experience, `J`'s added space is almost always a problem. When I write text it's cool but it sucks when I join HTML tags. I tend to use `:j!` instead.

Comment: Thanks William and romainl! Swapping? When I've read about swapping in your messages I've found another solution.  :m .-2 | :normal J

Comment: `gJ` does `J` without the space.

Answer (score 7):

You can also use the ex-command

```
:m-2|j
```

- `m-2` has the effect of moving the current line to 2 lines above its current position; this switches the position of the current line and the line above.
- `j` joins the current line and the line above, inserting a space between the two. Use `j!` if you don't want the space.
- `|` separates the 2 ex-commands

This ex-command is a short way of writing the following

```
:move .-2
:join
```

Answer (score 0):

I added the below lines to my .vimrc.  Now, in normal mode, I can either press @j or < leader >j.  Leader for me is space.  I've also seen people set it to ,.

```
" join with previous line with @j
let @j="kJ"
nnoremap <leader>j @j
```

If you haven't set leader yet, you can set it to space like this:

```
let mapleader = " "
let g:mapleader = " "
```

Comment: Why not skip the reg step and just `nnoremap <Leader>j kJ`?  Note this is the same as OPs `-J` in the question.

Comment: I used the register so that I could do a count at the beginning.  5kJ translates incorrectly to 5k and J which will join 2 lines that are 5 lines above the current one.  Whereas 5@j will translate correctly to joining the previous 5 lines.