# Append previous line to end of current in vim

Tags: vim

I'm looking for the best way to append the previous line to the current line like this:

```
# Bazzy Comment
foo = 'bar'
```

To this:

```
foo = 'bar' # Bazzy Comment
```

Currently I can do this:

*From top line*
<kbd>d</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>,<kbd>p</kbd>,<kbd>k</kbd>,<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>

Yank Link, paste, move cursor up, Join Lines

Basically I'm looking for a backward line join. I feel like there must be a better way to do this.

Comment: if you just do this occasionally, and only backwards join single line, leave with your solution, or like doelleri suggested, create a mapping. If you need backwards join multiple lines, there is plugin to do it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I Join the line above after current line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13609736/how-do-i-join-the-line-above-after-current-line)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method seems good to me.

```
ddpkJ
```

In a different editor you would do the following steps: select line, cut, delete blank line, move to end, enter space, and paste. So in Sublime Text it would be `<c-l><c-x><end><space><c-v><del>`.

Vim does it with less key strokes and less modifiers. I guess if you do this a bunch then you can speed this up by making a mapping.

Personally I would just leave it be and put efforts into more time consuming operations.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a builtin command for this. You can `nnoremap` those keys to another keystroke though. For example,

```
:nnoremap <M-J> ddpkJ
```